# Visual Studio 2012 .Net Trace Error

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am running into the following issue when starting Visual Studio 2012.

[image: When opening Visual Studio 2012]
[image: Then Trying to open a project]

Comment: Getting a message box from "Microsoft Visual Studio" before it is installed is ... special.  That bottom message box indicates that WIC is messed up.  That's very bad.  You'll need to get your machine stable first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I had to do the following in order

1. Remove Visual Studio(s) 2010 and 2012. 2008 Did not have this issue.
2. Then I removed .Net framework 4.5, 4.0, and re-install them both.
3. Then re-install the VS 2010, then 2012.
4. Run Windows Update. And All is well.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting and if it still does not work, re-download the installation media or verify it is correct with some checksum. If all of that still fails, grab the web installer and try that. If it still does not work, file a bug report on MS Connect.

A solution for a previous version of VS is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257817/visual-studio-2012-failed-to-create-project) and may be helpful, but it seems pretty hit or miss.

+1

Comment: Bascialy I had to do the following in order 1. Remove Visual Studio(s) 2010 and 2012. 2008 Did not have this issue. 2. Then I removed .Net framwork 4.5, 4.0, and re-install them both. 3. Then re-install the VS 2010, then 2012. Run Windows Update. And All is well. I will give you the point on this for the help.

Comment: @thechrisberry I wouldn't mind if you wrote out your solution that is in your comment, as an answer, and marked it as the correct one. The most accurate response is the one that should be marked after all. Thanks for writing out what worked for you, it's what makes SO great.