# Error when trying to start a new project in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

I just try to make a new project in Visual Studio 2013 Proffesional, but there is always this error

> "Failed to create a ImageSource from the text '..\Images\Medium.png'.
>   "

when clicking at "New Project". I haven't installed FastPictureViewer ore something. Additionally I have uninstalled and reinstalled VS, but the error is still there.

More Informations:
- I have installed Windows 8.1 Enterprise
- I can't login in VS
- Before the problem, I have tried to re-install the Net Framework (unfortunately without success).

Cristian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of:

- [Microsoft 1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab4a5425-8df4-4e89-9d82-6a6f5a8b4186/how-to-fix-below-error-when-creating-new-project-with-vs2012-ultimate-on-windows-80?forum=vssetup)
- [Microsoft 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2013/03/19/visual-studio-2012-ide-shows-failed-to-create-a-imagesource-from-the-text-images-medium-png-while-accessing-file-new-file-open-dialog-boxes.aspx)
- [StackOverflow 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2013/03/19/visual-studio-2012-ide-shows-failed-to-create-a-imagesource-from-the-text-images-medium-png-while-accessing-file-new-file-open-dialog-boxes.aspx)
- [StackOverflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257817/visual-studio-2012-failed-to-create-project)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I haven't installed any Codec Programm or FastPictuireVieweron my pc and I also tryed to run VS as an administrator.