# Method not found: 'Void System.Diagnostics.Tracing.FrameworkEventSource.BeginGetResponse(System.Object, System.String)'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, visual-studio-2013

I upgraded to windows 8.1 Today. After the upgrade I am experiencing the following exception on one of my WPF windows:

`XAML Exception: Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception`.

```
Inner Exception: Method not found: 'Void System.Diagnostics.Tracing.FrameworkEventSource.BeginGetResponse(System.Object, System.String)'.
```

I was not getting this exception before updating my windows. Note that when I remove the Icon from the window the exception  does not occur - `Icon="/MyProgram;component/Resources/language.png"`

Unhandled stack trace is a follows:

```
    Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
Stack:
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at MaxCut.App.Main()
```

Another issue which I am guessing is related to the one above: When I try to create a new project in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, I get the following Error

> "Failed to create a 'ImageSource' from the text '..\Images\Medium.png'

I have already tried the following solutions
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2013/03/19/visual-studio-2012-ide-shows-failed-to-create-a-imagesource-from-the-text-images-medium-png-while-accessing-file-new-file-open-dialog-boxes.aspx

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/830040/failed-to-create-a-imagesource-from-the-text-images-medium-png

[Visual Studio 2012 failed to create project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257817/visual-studio-2012-failed-to-create-project)

[Error when trying to start a new project in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045906/error-when-trying-to-start-a-new-project-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 5):

NET Framework 4.6 did the trick for me, hope it works for you as well!

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44928

Answer (score 4):

To anybody who comes across this issue. Note that that after installing he following two updates the problem was resolved:

Upgrade to windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3063843)

Upgrade to windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3068708)

Comment: IMO this should be the correct answer. On my machine, solely installing **KB3063843** helped. There was no need of installing .NET 4.6 or KB3068708 which are mentioned in these answers.

Answer (score 4):

I am running a new .NET WebApi site (.Net version 4.5.2) that builds locally on my work-managed Windows 7 PC, and deploys to Windows Server 2012 where I do not have upgrade permissions.

I was able to solve this problem and deploy my site by removing the nuget packages for:

- `Microsoft.AspNet.TelemtryCorrelation`
- `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource`

Comment: When I downgraded target from 4.6.1 to 4.5.2, run the PM command PM> Update-Package -Reinstall. Then remove the above two nugget packages. Clean the solution and Rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the application insights packages and Diagnostics package.

Answer (score 0):

A palliative is to disable the Application Insights in Azure Configuration
Menu for the application.

But the solution is upgrade System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource to the last version.