# Failed to create imageSource from the text '..\Images\Medium.png

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I recently migrated windows 8.1. But unable to open vs2013/vs2012 new Project template.

IT was working fine in windows 8.

ERROR:  **Failed to create imageSource from the text '..\Images\Medium.png'**

Tried all options but did not succeed.

Please HELP

Comment: I think the path mentioned wont exist, wherever you have used that image path, instead of writing full path like ..\Images\Medium.png, change it to ~/Images/Medium.png. It may work.

Comment: I have the same situation.. Tried almost every "solution" I could found but no luck... Please add here if you can find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you migrated from windows 8 to windows 8.1

- First Go to Control Panel --> Check Updates for Windows 8.1
- Install All Important Updates
- Restart Your Pc
- All things will properly work..

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost every solution I found.

I would like to share, what I have tried and did not work and what did work and solved the problem.

Here are the "solutions" which **did not work for me** but claimed that **they worked for some people**.

1) Removing FastPictureViewer Codec Pack (which was already not installed)

2) Having a modify permission to everyone for

```
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config
```

and

```
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config
```

3) Using [Procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/bb896645.aspx) to see broken registries

4) Uninstalling/reinstalling VS13 and all shared packages

5) Renaming the machine.config.default to machine.config

6) Running Visual Studio as an administrator

**And this what it solved it:**

Simply installed all the updates for windows 8.1 (not only the important ones, also optional updates as well) and restart. It sounds crazy after spending hours and hours but that solved my problem.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the steps mentioned above and it did not work. Even I was not able to uninstall VS.

I reapaired .NET framework through Contrl Panel->Programs and Features-> Microsoft .Net Framework-> right click Chane/Uninstall Repair .Net Framework.

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error after **Oracle Data Provider for VS 2013** installation. I installed all Windows 8.1 Important Updates but it didn't work. I read somewhere that it can be happened because of lastly installed VS Add-On etc. then uninstalled Oracle Data Provider for VS 2013 and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2012. This problem occurred to me after I upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1, so it is definitely related to the OS upgrade.

As some answers say, installing updates for Windows 8.1 will resolve the issue. But you don't need to install everything. I installed only the .NET related updates. Specifically, I installed "*Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 for Windows 8.1" (KB2934520)*, and a few others "*Security and Quality Rollup*" updates as well.

After a reboot, the "Loading Components" dialog shows up briefly upon launching Visual Studio, indicating that the cache of some components are invalidated and they are compiled again. After that, the "Add Reference" dialog works again.