# Locating corrupt Visual Studio user settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013

My copy of VS2015 has for several weeks had a problem in specific situations:

File > New > Project gives error message

> Failed to create a 'ImageSource' from the text '..\Images\Medium.png'

and same for solution folder right-click Add > New Item and Add > Class.

I have done everything to the VS2015 installation to try to resolve this - Uninstall, Total Uninstall, Reinstall, Repair, different Update version, etc - with no solution.

Then I recently discovered that if create a new local account on the machine, and run VS2015 from that new account, it works properly.  So the problem is obviously in my user profile somewhere.

I have tried clearing or replacing all the obvious areas, including these Registry paths

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio 
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSCommon
```

and the following areas of the User data

```
C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon
C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio
C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VSCommon
```

Still no good.

There are no clues when I compare devenv /log and ActivityLog.xml with both local accounts.

This is not related to the environment settings (Import/Export) it is something much deeper in the user account config.

From the errors I suspect it has something to do with the loading of the template icons into the dialogs that are supposed to appear at these points, perhaps a corrupt cache somewhere, but I can't find it and the error is no help.  Exhaustive searches have revealed nothing useful.

This is very frustrating, obviously I have an example of a working config in the new user account, but how can I identify which part of mine is faulty?  Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493701/failed-to-create-imagesource-from-the-text-images-medium-png

Comment: Thank Hans, but none of those solutions apply.  This is a Win10 machine.